# If X,Y~N(0,1), what's the probability that both X and X+Y are positive?

Tags: probability, statistics

this is what chat GPT gave me, wanted to make sure it's correct and why?

The variables X and Y are both standard normal random variables, i.e., they follow a normal distribution with mean 0 and standard deviation 1.

The variable Z = X + Y is also a normal random variable. The mean of Z is the sum of the means of X and Y, which is 0 + 0 = 0. The variance of Z is the sum of the variances of X and Y (since X and Y are independent), which is 1 + 1 = 2. Therefore, Z is a normal random variable with mean 0 and standard deviation $$\sqrt{2}$$.

The event that both X and Z are positive corresponds to the upper right quadrant of the (X, Z) plane. Because X and Z are bivariate normally distributed, this region corresponds to a quarter of the total probability, so the probability that both X and Z are positive is 0.25 or 25%.

This is because the joint distribution of (X, Z) is symmetric about both the X-axis and the Z-axis, and the four quadrants of the (X, Z) plane are equivalent.

So, the probability that both X and X+Y are positive is 0.25 or 25%.

Comment: you need the joint distribution to answer the question...

Comment: OK, you used ChatGPT,  but what do you understand about what ChatGPT said, and what parts are you simply regurgitating? Also I find it weird you used Marhjax to format your math expressions in only one spot and not the others.

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ normal does not necessarily make $X+Y$ normal. ChatGPT is not for Mathematics.

Comment: Note:  the OP does in fact declare that $X,Y$ are independent, though, confusingly, that's just tossed in via a parenthetic clause.  For clarity, that assumption should have been made explicitly at the start.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP used chatGPT.

Comment: @KurtG. I disagree with your reaction.  I am not aware of any rules that prohibit the OP (i.e. original poster) from attempting to use analysis from chatGPT, rather than a much more reliable source, such as a math textbook.  In judging whether a question should be closed, to me, the issue is not whether the OP has gone off the rails.  Instead, the issue is whether the OP has made a significant attempt (of some sort) to tackle the problem, and has made a reasonable attempt to document his work directly in the posted question.  In your opinion, does this posting meet those standards?

Comment: **To the OP (i.e. original poster):** Have you ever taken a college course in statistics?  Personally, I have not, which is why, if I was invited to attack this problem, I would pass.  That is, since I have no (formal, well organized) education in this part of math, I believe that I would be in over my head.

Answer (score 1):

That ChatGPT answer is completely incorrect.

First, it looks like ChatGPT has assumed that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, which wasn't part of the original prompt (assuming the question title is the verbatim prompt).  This extra assumption isn't made clear, except as a parenthetical note in only **one**, non-critical spot in the argument. Other, more critical parts of the argument -- $Z$ is normally distributed, the joint distribution of $X$ and $Z$ is bivariate normal -- rely on the independence assumption, but ChatGPT doesn't explain this.

Second, and more critically, even with the independence assumption added, ChatGPT incorrectly concludes that the bivariate normal distribution of $X$ and $Z$ is symmetric about the $X$ and $Z$ axes. This is false.  So, the final conclusion that the probability is 0.25 is also false.

It turns out that the correct answer under the assumption that $X$ and $Y$ are independent is 3/8.  This follows from a "radial symmetry" argument as in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3439651/401952).  Note that the probability given in that answer (of 3/4) is the conditional probability of $X+Y>0$ given $X>0$, but to calculate this, the answer identifies 8 equally likely cases where exactly 3 have both $X>0$ and $X+Y>0$, giving the probability 3/8.

Comment: "That ChatGPT answer is completely incorrect." As expected. +1.